# Does webpack remove this type of code automatically?

Tags: javascript, webpack

This is a good helper for development mode, but does this code get removed from bundles or is a particular plugin needed to remove it?  Seems like it would have to be removed since `process` is not available in the browser.  What setting causes this to happen?

The webpack docs aren't really all that clear about what these options do, just giving vague references:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/
and
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (typeof nextValue === 'undefined') {
        console.info(next);
        throw new Error('React Table: A reducer hook ☝️ just returned undefined! This is not allowed.');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`process.env.NODE_ENV` is actually available in the browser because Webpack creates the `process` variable as a global in code that is output. It is controlled via the Webpack configuration [`mode`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/).

You can set the mode in your config or the command line. If you use enivornment based Webpack configs (ie. webpack.dev.js, webpack.prod.js) they will automatically set the mode.

`webpack --mode=production`

Comment: So the code continues to exist after babel/webpack gets thru with it.  Meaning that it is evaluated at runtime in my production code?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Webpack is adding `process.env.NODE_ENV` to your bundle. You can then use this to intiialize feature flags and other environment specific controls at runtime.